# Tkinter Text Tagging Range From Start And End Indices Values From wordstart to wordend?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, tags, bind

I am attempting to modify some amazing code provided by Bryan Oakley that [highlights (tags) words in a tkinter Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981382/event-for-text-in-tkinter-text-widget) on a `ButtonRelease-1` event.

Instead of highlighting a single word, I'd like to click some text, drag my mouse to another area on the same line (left or right), and highlight that full range from that ranges `wordstart` and `wordend` boundaries.

For example, if I click the end of the first line after ***tk*** in the code below, drag my mouse to the ***p*** of the word ***import*** and release my mouse button, I want the tag to expand to capture the full range from `1.0` to `1.20`.

The below code uses two `tk.StringVar` to capture start and end strings but from those two indices obtained, how would I apply these start and end points to the range and then expand to highlight up to the `wordstart` and `wordend` range?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="none")
    self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    self.start = tk.StringVar()
    self.end = tk.StringVar()

    self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.button_down)
    self.text.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.button_up)
    #self.text.bind("<B1-Motion>", self._on_click)
    self.text.tag_configure("highlight", background="green", foreground="black")

    with open(__file__, "rU") as f:
      data = f.read()
      self.text.insert("1.0", data)

  def button_down(self, event):
    self.start.set(self.text.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y)))
    print(self.start.get())

  def button_up(self, event):
    self.end.set(self.text.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y)))
    print(self.end.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can append `"wordstart"` or `"wordend"` to any valid index. Also, you don't need to use a `StringVar` -- it adds complexity and provides no extra value over a normal variable:

Here's one way to do it:

```
def button_down(self, event):
    self.start = self.text.index('@%s,%s wordstart' % (event.x, event.y))

def button_up(self, event):
    self.end = self.text.index('@%s,%s wordend' % (event.x, event.y))

    self.text.tag_add("highlight", self.start, self.end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting "my" solution (based 99% on Bryan's code and help). If user highlights mouse from left-to-right vs right-to-left, I wasn't sure the "best" way to handle that so I compared the indexes as floats to see which was greater or less than and handled the `wordstart` and `wordend` accordingly.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="none")
    self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.button_down)
    self.text.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.button_up)

    self.text.tag_configure("highlight", background="green", foreground="black")

    with open(__file__, "rU") as f:
      data = f.read()
      self.text.insert("1.0", data)

  def button_down(self, event):
    self.xy_down = self.text.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y))
    self.start = self.text.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y))

  def button_up(self, event):
    self.stop = self.text.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y))
    self.xy_up = self.text.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y))
    if self.xy_down == self.xy_up:
      self.text.tag_remove('highlight', 1.0, 'end')
      self.text.tag_add("highlight", 'insert wordstart', 'insert wordend')
    elif float(self.start) > float(self.stop):
      #print('Highlight right to left')
      self.begin = self.text.index('%s wordend' % (self.start))
      self.end = self.text.index('%s wordstart' % (self.stop))
      self.text.tag_remove('highlight', 1.0, 'end')
      self.text.tag_add("highlight", self.end, self.begin)
      print(self.start, self.stop, self.begin, self.end)
    elif float(self.start) < float(self.stop):
      #print('Highlight left to right')
      self.begin = self.text.index('%s wordstart' % (self.start))
      self.end = self.text.index('%s wordend' % (self.stop))
      self.text.tag_remove('highlight', 1.0, 'end')
      self.text.tag_add("highlight", self.begin, self.end)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: comparing as floats will not always work, since `1.10` is considered less than `1.2` as floats, but `1.10` actually to the right of `1.2`. The text widget has a `compare` method specifically for comparing indices. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.compare-method

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I'd +100 if I could. I was wondering why it seemed buggy when I clicked the first line (wouldn't highlight reliably all the time).